# how to detect the landscape mode on rotation in ios7?

Tags: pdf, ios7

My app displays pdf pages,in portrait mode a single page is getting displayed(default mode is portrait).On rotating to landcscape it should display two pages side by side,
In my ViewController's viewdidloadmethod i have added the following,

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
{

        UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
        landscape=UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation);
    if(landscape)
    {
      //logic goes here
    }
    else
    {
     logic for portrait goes here
    }
}
```

But it's not working for me,only the portrait logic is getting excecuted.Please help

Answer (score 0):

Orientation changes are handled a bit different way.
Your viewcontroller needs to receive notification, when orientation changes.

Here's the sample code:

```
@implementation PortraitViewController
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                 selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                 name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                 object:nil];
}

- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIDeviceOrientation deviceOrientation = [UIDevice currentDevice].orientation;
    if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape(deviceOrientation) &&
        !isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        isShowingLandscapeView = YES;
        // logic for landscape orientation goes here
    }
    else if (UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait(deviceOrientation) &&
             isShowingLandscapeView)
    {
        isShowingLandscapeView = NO;
        // logic for portrait orientation goes here
    }
}
```

For futher information, check [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html)